# How to multiply a variable?

Tags: javascript, multiplication

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
//Add spaces between menu links
//Placement: Global Header
//Coded by Game

var spaces = "2";  //Edit number of spaces between menu links (1,2 or 3)

var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i].parentNode.parentNode.className == "menubg" && a[i].innerHTML.match(/Home|new topics|help|search|members|calendar|admin|profile|logout|register|login/i)) {
        if (spaces == "1") {
        a[i].innerHTML += "&nbsp;";
        }
        if (spaces == "2") {
        a[i].innerHTML += "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        }
        if (spaces == "3") {
        a[i].innerHTML += "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        }
    }   
}
</script>
```

The code above is meant to let the useer add spaces between their menu items. It works fine. But how do I make it to where they can add as many spaces as they would like, instead of limiting them to 3? Maybe somehow they would add their number in the var 'spaces' and the code would multiply &nbsp by that numvber?

Answer (score 4):

Just use a loop:

```
var spaces = 2; 

[..]

for(var i = 0; i < spaces; ++ i)
    a[i].innerHTML += "&nbsp";
```

Answer (score 1):

I would generate the string in a separate method, like:

```
function getSpaces(count) {
var spaces = "";
for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
       spaces += "&nbsp";
}
return spaces;
}
```

and then

```
a[i].innerHTML = getSpaces(2); //etc
```

This way you set innerHTML and access the array only one time, and also don't have repeated code.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create a loop inside your `if` clause that adds an `&nbsp;` every time you go through the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Avoid `innerHTML` if you can, since it deletes and recreates the entire content of the element. Prefer `appendChild` and `createTextNode` instead. For instance:

```
a[i].appendChild(document.createTextNode(new Array(spaces + 1).join("\u00A0")));
```